# Insert Cover as Double Page

Tags: books

I am ready to send my `project` (`class = book, A4`) to the printer as a PDF. But they request that I insert--in the beginning of the document--the book cover as a double-page with `0.8 cm` thickness for the `spine`. This is because the cover is printed separately. The cover is simple, just the title of the book "The Blessed Lord Said" and my name as the author. I have looked online but have not been able to find any information on how to configure this into a `Latex class = book` document. Is there anyone that has experience with this?

Comment: I would make the cover as a separate document, then just concatenate the cover and the internal pages if the printer really wants it as a single document.

Comment: `zwpagelayout.sty` may helps you, it has nice documentation also....

Comment: But you should keep the `cover` as separate file as `David Purton` mentioned, that is the better way...